# Why is it showing Error : CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "$this.categoryId" at path "category" for model "Product"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongoose

I am using nodejs with MongoDB in the backend to create my application and Angular to the front-end. As I try to get the value from the postman for the 'products' under a specific 'category' the Postman responds with success message and delivers the values. But the real problem arises when I try to view through the front end.

It shows the following error once I try to get the products inside the specific category:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "$this.categoryId" at path "category" for model "Product"
    at model.Query.exec
```

I have checked the backend and it runs smoothly without any error. I guess the error meant'categoryId' parameter is not getting the valid value but it can't be as my localhost is redirected to the individual categoryId link `http://localhost:4200/categories/5f004ae05ca53a0da8d5c043` but it is not able to load the product inside the category.

Here is how I have written code in my TypeScript `category.component.ts`,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router' ;
import { RestApiService } from '../rest-api.service' ;
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.scss']
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  categoryId: any;
  category: any;
  page = 1;

  constructor(
    private data: DataService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private rest: RestApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(res => {
      this.categoryId = res['_id'];
      this.getProducts();
    });
  }

  get lower() {
    return 10 * (this.page - 1) + 1;
  }

  get upper() {
    return Math.min(10 * this.page, this.category.totalProducts);
  }

  async getProducts(event ?: any) {
    if (event) {
      this.category = null;
    }
    try {
      const data = await this.rest.get(
        'http://localhost:397/api/categories/$this.categoryId?page=${this.page -1}'
      );
      data['success']  
        ? (this.category = data)
        :this.data.error(data['message']);
    }catch (error) {
      
    }
  }

}
```

How could I fix this issue? I am hopeful for positive responses.

Comment: post the server side code, remove the angular code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the `try catch` block towards the end of your code you seem to have mistakenly wrapped the request URL in normal quotes `''` instead of back ticks ``` `` ```.

Which is why mongoose is showing a cast error, as it is unable to parse `$this.categoryId`. Try this instead:

```
  const data = await this.rest.get(
    `http://localhost:397/api/categories/${this.categoryId}?page=${this.page -1}`
  );
```

Comment: wow I have been sending all the links in the normal quotes and didn't really know the difference. I am so thankful mate. Thank you again.